# one Button for multiple thing

Tags: android, android-button

I just want to implement one button to do multiple actions like on first click make **Textview1 visible** and on second click **make Textview2 visible** and so on.

**here is my code** it works but for 2 actions only i want to set more visible component in one button i hope its clear and Thanks for any help

```
    final TextView textView_r4 = findViewById(R.id.tv_r4);
    final EditText editText_r4 = findViewById(R.id.input_R4);
    final TextView textView_r5 = findViewById(R.id.tv_r5);
    final EditText editText_r5 = findViewById(R.id.input_R5);

    findViewById(R.id.Addbtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView_r4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editText_r4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.Addbtn).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            textView_r5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editText_r5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
       }
    });
```

Comment: You could just type more instructions before `return true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `enum` State to keep track of which state your button is in. Create a class field in the same class (activity) that these methods are in, and change the state every time you click. Then in the `.setOnClickListener` method you can check which state the button is in, and depending on that do different actions.

```
private State state = INITIAL;

findViewById(R.id.Addbtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (state) {
            case INITIAL:
                // do first action
                state = State.CLICKED_ONCE;
                break;
            case CLICKED_ONCE:
                // do second action
                state = State.CLICKED_TWICE;
                break;
            default:
                // clicked too many times, no action taken
                break;
        }
    }
});

private enum State { INITIAL, CLICKED_ONCE, CLICKED_TWICE }
```

Comment: hi ty for replay, i tried this the  INITIAL, CLICKED_ONCE, CLICKED_TWICE in switch statement shows red error "Cant resolve symbol"

Comment: You need to add the State enum: private enum State { INITIAL, CLICKED_ONCE, CLICKED_TWICE }

Comment: I do i add it. But maybe wrong placement. I placed it outside oncreate and I tried and placed it inside same error

Comment: try replacing them with State.INITIAL, State.CLICKED_ONCE, State.CLICKED_TWICE